# Jaxb: Validate child element

Tags: xml, validation, jaxb

How do I validate a child element in Jaxb? I used the code below:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TCreateRecord.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(XSD_URL);
marshaller.setSchema(schema);
marshaller.marshal(createRecord, new DefaultHandler());
```

First I got

```
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "ru.egisso.types.package_reg._1_0.TPackage$Elements$CreateRecord" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

But after changing the code and using `JAXBElement` as shown below:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TCreateRecord.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(XSD_URL);
marshaller.setSchema(schema);

QName _Package_QNAME = new QName("urn://egisso-ru/types/package-REG/1.0.1", "createRecord");
JAXBElement<TCreateRecord> jaxbElement=new JAXBElement<TCreateRecord>(_Package_QNAME,TCreateRecord.class,null,createRecord);

marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, new DefaultHandler());
```

I got another one:

```
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: Instance of "ru.egisso.types.package_reg._1_0.TPackage$Elements$CreateRecord" is substituting "ru.egisso.types.package_reg._1_0.TCreateRecord", but "ru.egisso.types.package_reg._1_0.TPackage$Elements$CreateRecord" is bound to an anonymous type.]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with the solution that doesn't solve the problem described in the question but it does what I need. I've set a listener to the marshaller in which I can count the elements of particular type that have already been marshalled.

```
marshaller.setListener(new Marshaller.Listener() {
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void afterMarshal(Object source) {
        if (source instanceof TCreateRecord) {
            appendToLogAndView("Record " + (++i) + " of " + createRecords + " is written");
        }
        super.afterMarshal(source);
    }
});
```